# Check what HTML tags generated by ASP.NET MVC 4 Html helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

During debugging views in ASP.NET MVC 4, I'd like to know what HTML tags have been generated right after a HTML helper call. Say I have a call `Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)` in the view. I set up a breakpoint right after this call in the view. When it stops here while debugging, now I want to check what exactly HTML tags are generated by that Html helper before sending to be rendered. Is there a way to do this? Thanks,

Comment: Download the source code and step through it

Comment: When it breaks on your line, open the Immediate Window in visual studio and execute the Html helper in there.  You'll see the returned values there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in ASP.NET MVC4, if **Razor** is the view engine, then simple. During debugging views, the follow can show the HTML string constructed so far in the *Watch* window (checked in **VS2012**).

```
this.ViewContext.Writer // System.IO.TextWriter {System.IO.StringWriter}
this.ViewContext.Writer.ToString()
```

or

```
this.GetOutputWriter()  // it returns this.ViewContext.Writer.
```

If the traditional **aspx** view engine is used, I haven't found a similar way to show it during debugging view, as I cannot get its `Writer` or `InnerWriter` properties shown below to do so. But we can always use **VS2015** to debug the view, and VS2015's **new feature** of showing the just returned values of function calls in the *Locals* window can tell us the constructed HTML string returned from the last Html helper call ***:)***

```
this.Writer //  {System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter}
this.Writer.InnerWriter // System.IO.TextWriter {System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.SwitchWriter}
```

Answer (score 0):

Point to be remember:-

It will be always **HTML helper always**, until render event will not come into picture, So before render event you will get always HTML helper only.

You can see the **rendered HTML in developer tool**.